# Same Formula responds multiple different ways

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, formulas, array-formulas

I created a formula that doesn't always act the same way. The reason I say that is I've copied and pasted from multiple columns and it works one way and then another.

```
{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('ODG Jobs'!$A$1:$Q$150,SMALL(IF('ODG Jobs'!$C:$C=$B$3,ROW('ODG Jobs'!$C:$C)),ROW('ODG Jobs'!$1:$150)),5)),"",INDEX('ODG Jobs'!$A$1:$Q$150,SMALL(IF('ODG Jobs'!$C:$C=$B$3,ROW('ODG Jobs'!$C:$C)),ROW('ODG Jobs'!$1:$150)),5))}
```

It works to pull data for a duplicate value, but if I try to drag the formula it won't drag properly or it will mess up the formula. I understand to press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> to get the array, but the same formula acts in two different ways is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this non-CSE formula which still allows array processing like SUMPRODUCT.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('ODG Jobs'!$E:$E, aggregate(15, 6, (row($1:$150)/('ODG Jobs'!$C$1:$C$150=$B$3), row(1:1)), 1), text(,))
```

Drag down for the second, third, etc matches.

Comment: As always good work with this formua +1, however it seems that it has a small typo-error, and instead of:  `=IFERROR(INDEX('ODG Jobs'!$E:$E, aggregate(15, 6, (row($1:$150)/('ODG Jobs'!$C$1:$C$150=$B$3), row(1:1)), 1), text(,))`  it should be:  `=IFERROR(INDEX('ODG Jobs'!$E:$E, AGGREGATE(15, 6, (ROW($1:$150)/('ODG Jobs'!$C$1:$C$150=$B$3)), ROW(1:1)), 1), TEXT(,))`  replace: `=$B$3), row(1:1))` with: `=$B$3)), ROW(1:1))`